# Hierarchical Bayesian model - issues with JAGS/BUGS switching between lognormal and normal

Tags: bayesian, lognormal-distribution, jags, bugs

I'm trying to construct a hierarchical model using JAGS, but I'm running into issues converting between normal/lognormal distributions and the more I stare at my problem, the more confused I get.

Some of the parameters I'm trying to estimate are a series of $M$ values - I know that $M$ is lognormally distributed. In order to estimate the mean of $M$ (the hierarchy), I want to use the normal distribution because I have prior information that the mean is likely around $0.2$.

I know that the following equations hold for when you 'switch' between inputting your values from a normal distribution (let's call it $X$) and a lognormal ($Y$, where $Y=\ln(X)$):

$\mu_Y = \ln(\mu_X) - 0.5\ln(1 + \frac{\sigma_X^2}{\mu^2_X}) = \ln (\mu_X) -0.5\sigma_Y^2$

$\sigma_Y^2 = \ln(1 + \frac{\sigma_X^2}{\mu^2_X})$

However, I'm having issues implementing these in my JAGS model code. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
meanM ~ dnorm(0.2, 0.1)
precM ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
varM <- 1 / precM
logvarM <- log(1 + (varM / (meanM * meanM)))
logprecM <- 1 / logvarM
logmeanM <- log(meanM) - (0.5 * logvarM)

for (k in 1:4){
  M[k] ~ dlnorm(logmeanM, logprecM)
}
```

I get an error from JAGS here that says that logmeanM has an `invalid parent value`, and when I try to debug it using OpenBUGS it says that `something went wrong in procedure Ln in module Math`. Am I completely wrong in my math or my code? The more I try to figure it out, the more confused about normal/lognormal I get, so apologies if that is reflected in this question.

Answer (score 1):

`meanM` is apparently intended to be the mean of a lognormal random variable. The mean of a lognormal distribution cannot be negative. Therefore, you cannot put a normal prior on `meanM` since a normal distribution puts positive probability on negative values.

Comment: I thought of that, but I tried setting up something like `meanM ~ dnorm(5, 10)`, which has little probability of having a negative value, and I still got the same error.

Comment: Even if the probability is small, it might happen once in a long simulation. Once is enough ...  The message *something went wrong in procedure Ln in module Math* should be clear enough ...